# Verify invoking a private and static method with ArgumentCaptor

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have a **private and static method** in a class with **private constructor**:

```
    private static void foo(Obj1 obj1, Obj2 obj2)
    {
        //some implementation
    }
```

I used reflection to invoke it since it is private in my test like that:

```
    Method ReflectionMethod = MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(
                "foo", Obj1.class, Obj2.class);
    ReflectionMethod.setAccessible(true);
    ReflectionMethod.invoke(null,obj1, obj2);
```

I invoke `foo` three times with different parameters in my test and I need to capture its arguments to be sure they are modified in `foo`.

When I try to capture arguments like this, the size of the list of obj1s becomes 0.

```
    ArgumentCaptor<Obj1> obj1Capture = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Obj1.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<Obj2> obj2Capture = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Obj2.class);

    verifyPrivate(MyClass.class, times(3)).invoke("foo", 
    obj1Capture.capture(), obj2Capture.capture());
    List<Obj1> obj1s = obj1Capture.getAllValues();
```

The list `obj1s`' size should have been three.

I think I am in wrong way while verifying a private static method, because I did same things for a private non-static method and it worked.

I really need help.

P.S. I mustn't change access modifiers of the `foo`.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you care if a private method was called? Why can't you assert the objects' state? What do you really want to test? Testing implementation details (private functions) is usually not the best path forward.

Comment: If you have any idea, please share. I want to be sure that the method is calling with correct arguments and I assign some values from them to another local variables.

Comment: I'll ask again: why do you care if a _private_ method is being called with certain arguments? Why can't you assert the state of the objects? Can you change the implementation of `foo` to call a (public) method of a different class/object?